# How to print raw query from WP_Query class just like in CodeIgniter

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

I am struggling with WordPress, and was looking at `WP_Query`. We usually pass an array of arguments to get result against.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_per_page' => '2',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Is there any way to print out `$the_query` in raw form for testing purpose just like we do in CodeIgniter with `$this->db->last_query();`?

Raw Query Example:

```
select * from table1 where ......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generated SQL is available via the `request` property:

```
echo $the_query->request;
```

where `$the_query` is a `\WP_Query` instance.

Check out how it's formed in the [class](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8cfdf4dd3a282d58ca524eec742779f3ec708f65/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2786) here.

Also available  via the [`posts_request`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8cfdf4dd3a282d58ca524eec742779f3ec708f65/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2797) filter for *unsuppressed* filtering.